# plot a groupby object with bokeh

Tags: pandas, pandas-groupby, bokeh

Consider the following MWE.

```py
from pandas import DataFrame
from bokeh.plotting import figure
data = dict(x = [0,1,2,0,1,2],
            y = [0,1,2,4,5,6],
            g = [1,1,1,2,2,2])
df = DataFrame(data)
p = figure()
p.line( 'x', 'y', source=df[ df.g == 1 ] )
p.line( 'x', 'y', source=df[ df.g == 2 ] )
```

Ideally, I would like to compress the last to lines in one:

```py
p.line( 'x', 'y', source=df.groupby('g') )
```

(Real life examples have a large and variable number of groups.) Is there any concise way to do this?

Answer (score 1):

I just found out that the following works

```py
gby = df.groupby('g')
gby.apply( lambda d: p.line( 'x', 'y', source=d ) )
```

(it has some drawbacks, though).

Any better idea?

Answer (score 1):

I didn't come out with `df.groupby` so I used `df.loc` but maybe multi_line is what you are after:

```
from pandas import DataFrame
from bokeh.plotting import figure, show
from bokeh.models import ColumnDataSource

data = dict(x = [0, 1, 2, 0, 1, 2],
            y = [0, 1, 2, 4, 5, 6],
            g = [1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2])

df = DataFrame(data, index = data['g'])
dfs = [DataFrame(df.loc[i].values, columns = df.columns) for i in df['g'].unique()]
source = ColumnDataSource(dict(x = [df['x'].values  for df in dfs], y = [df['y'].values for df in dfs]))

p = figure()
p.multi_line('x', 'y', source = source)

show(p)
```

Result:

[image]

Comment: Thank you. I missed multi_line. I posted a somewhat cleaner solution.

Comment: Unfortunately, the proposed answer only work with lines.  There is no `multi_dots` methods etc.

Answer (score 1):

This is Tony's solution slightly simplified.

```py
import pandas as pd
from bokeh.plotting import figure
data = dict(x = [0, 1, 2, 0, 1, 2],
            y = [0, 1, 2, 4, 5, 6],
            g = [1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2])
df = pd.DataFrame(data)
####################### So far as in the OP
gby = df.groupby('g')
p = figure()
x = [list( sdf['x'] ) for i,sdf in gby]
y = [list( sdf['y'] ) for i,sdf in gby]
p.multi_line( x, y )
```

Comment: This plot generates different lines then intended: x_range = (6, 8) instead of the original x_range = (0, 2)

Answer (score 0):

```
from pandas import DataFrame
from bokeh.plotting import figure, show
from bokeh.models import ColumnDataSource

data = dict(x = [0, 1, 2, 0, 1, 2],
            y = [0, 1, 2, 4, 5, 6],
            g = [1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2])

df = DataFrame(data)

plt = figure()
for i, group in df.groupby(['g']):
    source = ColumnDataSource(group)
    plt.line('x','y', source=source, legend_group='g')

show(plt)
```