# How to plot a line for every group in Pandas dataframe with Bokeh

Tags: python, pandas, bokeh

I grouped a pandas dataframe into

```
                 registrationtime objecthandling  counts
0  2020-01-23 06:01:57.176000+00:00         Create       2
1  2020-01-23 06:01:57.176000+00:00         Delete       1
2  2020-01-23 06:01:57.176000+00:00   buildingUUID       1
3  2020-01-23 06:04:59.723000+00:00   buildingUUID       1
4  2020-01-23 06:07:37.707000+00:00   buildingUUID       1
5  2020-01-23 06:29:48.102000+00:00         Delete       2
6  2020-01-23 06:33:03.946000+00:00   buildingUUID       2
7  2020-01-23 06:34:15.447000+00:00   buildingUUID       1
8  2020-01-23 06:38:19.964000+00:00         Create       2
9  2020-01-23 06:38:19.964000+00:00         Delete       1
10 2020-01-23 06:41:17.589000+00:00         Create       1
11 2020-01-23 06:41:17.589000+00:00         Delete       2
12 2020-01-23 06:44:51.089000+00:00         Create       2
13 2020-01-23 06:44:51.089000+00:00         Delete       2
14 2020-01-23 06:44:51.089000+00:00       geometry       1
```

and I want to plot lines in Bokeh where the x-axis is *datetime* and thereby column *registrationtime*, and the y-axis is *counts*. However, I need a separate line depending on the column *objecthandling* -> Create, delete, buildingUUID, geometry. In this case four different lines

My code so far

```
obj_handling_group = gdf.groupby(['registrationtime', 'objekthandling']).size().reset_index(name='counts')
source = ColumnDataSource(obj_handling_group)
p = figure(plot_height=350, plot_width=800, x_axis_type='datetime')
p.line(x='registrationtime', y='counts', source=source, color='navy')
```

Obviously this gives me one line, but how do I separate the data based on the values in column *objecthandling*?

Answer (score 0):

You could combine `df.groupby` with Bokeh `multiline` like in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55592101/plot-a-groupby-object-with-bokeh/55594762#55594762)